# Exclude duplicate pair from List<model, model>

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

In result of my select

```
var names = _db.Messages
            .Where(p => p.UserId == parameters.UserId || p.ToUserId == parameters.UserId)
                    .Select(p => new {p.FirstUser, p.SecondUser})
            .Distinct()
            .ToList();
```

I get four elements of type List<User, User>.

[image: select]

As you can see I have one duplicates

[0] and [2]. Only in sequence FirstUser and SecondUser they have difference

How can I Exclude one of them in query before `ToList()` ? And it will be perfect if in result I will have `List<User>` with all of them without duplicates.

Comment: so `FirstUser` != `SecondUser` ?

Comment: This looks like Entity Framework, and a bit of an XY problem. Are you wanting a distinct list of users or a distinct list of from->to? Either way, I'm not sure the dupe actually answer this properly.

Comment: `Distinct` takes an optional `IEqualityComparer<T>` that you can use as well. You'd need to implement that interface and define a new abstraction for your anonymous type, though

Comment: Before people start jumping in to explain equality comparers, please note this is Entity Framework so that is not necessarily relevant.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/csc16seZTVvKfM4VMtCZW1/0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks that you don't care about who send the message and who received it. This is a solution for you:

```cs
var names = 
   _db.Messages
   .Where(p => p.UserId == parameters.UserId || p.ToUserId == parameters.UserId)
   .Select(p => new {
          user1 = p.UserId > p.ToUserId ? p.FirstUser.Id : p.SecondUser.Id,
          user2 = p.UserId <= p.ToUserId ? p.FirstUser.Id : p.SecondUser.Id,
          })
   .Distinct()
   .ToList();
```

Comment: My UserId is Guid Type, so I can't compare it.

Comment: in result I have the same, only user1 and user2 changed places, maybe can we now check for the same object in select array on this stage? https://paste.pics/94848ed61c22c0ad85539768ab5f82dc

Comment: It is work if I return `p.FirstUser.Id` or `p.SecondUser`. Add it to your answer and I check it such right.

Comment: I mean that if you change `p.FirstUser to `p.FirstUser.Id` and `p.SecondUser` to `p.SecondUser.Id` it will be the right answer